# Tensorflow tf.nn.in_top_k Error targets[0] is out of range

Tags: matrix, tensorflow

I have a tensorflow program with four output labels. I trained the model and am now evaluating separate data with it.

The issue is that after I use the code

```
import tensorflow as tf

import main
import Process
import Input

eval_dir = "/Users/Zanhuang/Desktop/NNP/model.ckpt-30"
checkpoint_dir = "/Users/Zanhuang/Desktop/NNP/checkpoint"


def evaluate():
  with tf.Graph().as_default() as g:
    images, labels = Process.eval_inputs()
    forward_propgation_results = Process.forward_propagation(images)
    init_op = tf.initialize_all_variables()
    saver = tf.train.Saver()
    top_k_op = tf.nn.in_top_k(forward_propgation_results, labels, 1)

  with tf.Session(graph=g) as sess:
    sess.run(init_op)
    saver.restore(sess, eval_dir)
    tf.train.start_queue_runners(sess=sess)
    print(sess.run(top_k_op))

def main(argv=None):
    evaluate()

if __name__ == '__main__':
  tf.app.run()
```

In total, I only have one class.

My code for the error rate, where I introduce the labels in a one hot matrix is here:

```
def error(forward_propagation_results, labels):
    labels = tf.one_hot(labels, 4)
    tf.transpose(labels)
    labels = tf.cast(labels, tf.float32)
    mean_squared_error = tf.square(tf.sub(labels, forward_propagation_results))
    cost = tf.reduce_mean(mean_squared_error)
    train = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(learning_rate = 0.05).minimize(cost)
    tf.histogram_summary('accuracy', mean_squared_error)
    tf.add_to_collection('losses', cost)

    tf.scalar_summary('LOSS', cost)

    return train, cost
```

Comment: This error suggests a mismatch between the shape of `forward_propagation_results` (assumed to be a matrix of size `b x c`) and the values in `labels` (assumed to be a vector of length `b` with all values < `c`). Can you try adding the statement `print(forward_propagation_result, sess.run(labels))` before the line that fails?

Comment: Sure: This is my result: (<tf.Tensor 'local3/Softmax:0' shape=(1, 4) dtype=float32>, array([40], dtype=int32))

Answer (score 0):

The problem is invalid data in your `labels` tensor. From [your comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38646328/tensorflow-tf-nn-in-top-k-error-targets0-is-out-of-range?noredirect=1#comment64677380_38646328), the `labels` tensor is a vector containing a single value: `[40]`. The value 40 is larger than the number of columns in the `forward_propagation_result` (which is 4).

The `tf.nn.in_top_k(predictions, targets, k)` op has the following behavior:

- For each row `predictions[i, :]`:

  - `result[i]` is true if `predictions[i, targets[i]]` is one of the k largest elements in that row; otherwise it is false.

There is no value `predictions[0, 40]`, because (as your comment shows) that argument is a `1 x 4` matrix. Therefore TensorFlow gives you an `out of range` error. This suggests that either your evaluation data are wrong, or you should be using a different evaluation function.

Comment: What do you mean by wrong? It is in the exact format as CIFAR 10. And also, what do you mean by a different evaluation function. I only know of the k_top

Comment: The evaluation example that you're feeding to the network assumes that the label of the class is 40. Your network produces 4 outputs for each example, which `tf.nn.in_top_k()` interprets as scores for the labels 0, 1, 2, and 3. Either the evaluation data are wrong (could be corrupt for example, if you only expect to have 4 different labels), or the network itself is wrong (it should produce at least 41 outputs per example so that label 40 is valid).

Comment: I can't see where my code went wrong in the network but may be the data. The network had trained without trouble and decreased the right way. You said something about using a different evaluation function. How would you do that?

Comment: The proper evaluation function depends on how you want to interpret the output of your network. Your network has four output units. What do they correspond to? What does the label 40 mean? In your `error()` function it looks like you were only expecting four classes (from the call to `tf.one_hot()`). Does this mean your training data only had labels between 0 and 3?

Comment: I was expecting four labels, and it did train properly with four labels, so I wouldn't expect it to go wrong. I had four labels and were only expecting one class. Also I have no clue how I got the label 40. The code looks right, or else it wouldn't have worked. Could it be the way I stored the checkpoint and .ckpt? And I thought there was only one eval function.

Comment: Ah, in that case the problem is either in the data file or in the `Process.eval_inputs()` function, which produces the `labels` tensor.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/118585/discussion-between-zan-huang-and-mrry).