# Tensorflow Strange Label Size

Tags: tensorflow

I have built a tensorflow conv net and saved it into the checkpoint file. After unpacking it in the eval program I got an error: targets[0] is out of range

But I managed to debug the program by printing out the labels and the forward propagation results. After printing them I found that the labels have a dimension of [0, 40] which shouldn't happen as compared to the forward propagation results [1, 4]. I am absolutely certain that the data has not been tampered with or damaged. Its in the same file format as cifar 10. The network seems fine. I think its the way I saved them. I didn't put in a checkpoint file or any of that.

This is the code in the main section of the program:

```
def train():
    with tf.Session() as sess:
        images, labels = Process.inputs()

        forward_propgation_results = Process.forward_propagation(images)

        train_loss, cost = Process.error(forward_propgation_results, labels)

        image_summary_t = tf.image_summary(images.name, images, max_images=1)

        summary_op = tf.merge_all_summaries()

        init = tf.initialize_all_variables()

        saver = tf.train.Saver()

        sess.run(init)

        saver = tf.train.Saver(tf.all_variables())

        tf.train.start_queue_runners(sess = sess)

        train_dir = "/Users/Zanhuang/Desktop/NNP/model.ckpt"

        summary_writer = tf.train.SummaryWriter(train_dir, sess.graph)

        for step in range(50):
            start_time = time.time()
            print(sess.run([train_loss, cost]))
            duration = time.time() - start_time
            if step % 1 == 0:
                num_examples_per_step = FLAGS.batch_size
                examples_per_sec = num_examples_per_step / duration
                sec_per_batch = float(duration)

                format_str = ('%s: step %d, (%.1f examples/sec; %.3f ''sec/batch)')
                print (format_str % (datetime.now(), step, examples_per_sec, sec_per_batch))

                summary_str = sess.run(summary_op)
                summary_writer.add_summary(summary_str, step)

                if step % 30 == 0:
                    checkpoint_path = train_dir
                    saver.save(sess, checkpoint_path, global_step=step)


def main(argv = None):
    train()

if __name__ == '__main__':
  tf.app.run()
```

Also: Earlier in the program, I one hot encoded the labels and trained without issue. So this shouldn't arise.

Update:

I ran a for loop on the label size for 50 iterations:

I received:

```
[40]
[120]
[120]
[92]
[48]
[92]
[120]
[120]
[92]
[48]
[92]
[120]
[92]
[92]
[48]
[100]
[120]
[48]
[48]
[120]
[48]
[92]
[48]
[48]
[48]
[48]
[120]
[120]
[48]
[48]
[48]
[48]
[92]
[120]
[48]
[48]
[92]
[120]
[48]
[92]
[48]
[48]
[120]
[48]
[120]
[48]
[92]
[92]
[120]
[48]
```

The following is how I generated the training data:

```
import numpy as np
import cPickle as pk
from PIL import Image
import os

def loadImage(filename):
    return Image.open(filename)


def pickle_data(filename, data, mode='wb'):
    with open(filename, mode) as file:
        pk.dump(data, file)


def unpickle_data(filename, mode = 'rb'):
    with open(filename, mode) as file:
        data = pk.load(file)
    return data


def loadAllPic():
    dict = {}
    imgdata = []
    imglabel = []

    for file in glob.glob('*.jpg'):
        print file
        img = loadImage(file)
        rawdata = img.load()
        redchannel = [rawdata[x, y][0] for x in range(img.width) for y in range(img.height)]
        greenchannel = [rawdata[x, y][1] for x in range(img.width) for y in range(img.height)]
        bluechannel = [rawdata[x, y][2] for x in range(img.width) for y in range(img.height)]
        nparray = np.array(redchannel + greenchannel + bluechannel)
        imgdata.append(nparray)
        imglabel.append("Gleason_4")
        dict['data'] = imgdata
        dict['labels'] = imglabel
        return dict


def main():
    dict = loadAllPic()
    pickle_data('Prostate_Cancer_Data2.binary', dict)

    data = unpickle_data('Prostate_Cancer_Data2.binary')
    print data.viewkeys()
    print data['labels'][:100]
    print data['data'][0]



if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

The above is for a single label. There are four programs. Each customized for a different label.

Comment: As we discussed in the [other question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/38647473/3574081), there seems to be a problem with your evaluation data. It looks like there are four distinct labels (40, 48, 92, and 120) but your neural network and `tf.nn.in_top_k()` expect the labels to be encoded as 0, 1, 2, and 3, corresponding to the respective column of the output of your network. How did you generate the training data, and how did you generate the evaluation data?

Comment: I will add in the code for the training data. A part of the training data is part of the evaluation data.

Comment: The training data program doesn't appear to generate data in the CIFAR format. The CIFAR format (which I gather you use for input reading) is a binary format containing fixed length records, with one byte for the class, followed by (height * width * channels) bytes for the image data. Do you have separate code for transforming the training data to binary?

Comment: No. I don't have a separate program for doing that. I managed to write this code after looking at the. Cifar 10 format on their website. They used pickle so did I.

Comment: How would I write such a program and how did it train on this format in the first place?

Comment: I assume you mean [this page](https://www.cs.toronto.edu/~kriz/cifar.html)? The TensorFlow function that you are using parses the "Binary version" of the CIFAR data and not the "Python / Matlab version" (which uses pickle).

Comment: Yes. Oh I understand now. How do I create the binary version? And does tensorflow have a feature for the regular version? And how come it started training normally?